# Remove Falsy values from array solved but not understood

Tags: javascript, arrays, falsy

I just solved this challenge on freecodecamp

`Remove all falsy values from an array. Return a new array; do not mutate the original array.
Falsy values in JavaScript are false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN.
Hint: Try converting each value to a Boolean.`

i solved mine this way:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(ele){return ele});
}
```

as opposed to this solved by freecodecamp:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {

  var check = arr.filter(function(i) {
    return Boolean(i);
  });

  return check;
}
```

I can't understand why mine works correctly when called with `bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);`, since i'm just returning the variable in the test function without doing the boolean conversion.

Comment: [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) coerces the return value to a boolean. See the [spec (step 7.c.ii)](//tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.filter). Note that `.filter(Boolean)` is the idiomatic version.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the concept of [`Truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [`Falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

Using `Array.filter(Boolean)` or `Array.filter(ele => ele)` is pretty much the same. `Boolean` will cast your value to a boolean value which can only be `true` or `false`. If you return just the value, it gets evaluated either as truthy or falsy.
If you would like to write it in a very explicit way you could do the following:

```js
Array.filter(ele => {
  return ele !=== undefined || ele !== null || ele !== false || ele !== '' || ele !== 0 || ele !== NaN
})
```